# How to create a "CHOICES" filter field from a model based on unique values from another model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Good day!

I would be very grateful for any help.

I have two related tables - Django models.

The field "nomer_kotl = models.TextField()" has an association with another model.

And as "choices = CHOICES" I would like to have "unique" values from the "Nomerkotelnoy(models.Model)" model.

How can I make the "choices = CHOICES" of the model (EmployeeModel(models.Model)) get the values from the field "nomer_kotl = models.TextField()" of the model (Nomerkotelnoy(models.Model)) ?

When creating a form for selecting data from a model table for display in an application on a site. - I think how can I make the form have a choice in the form of "select dropdown" - the choice of only one value.

```
class Nomerkotelnoy(models.Model):
    nomer_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    nomer_kotl = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nomer_kotl

CHOICES = (
    ("1", "1"),
    ("2", "2"),
    ("3", "3"),
    ("4", "4"),
    ("5", "5"),
    ("6", "6"),
    ("7", "7"),
    ("8", "8"),
)


class EmployeeModel(models.Model):
    empid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    empname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    joindate = models.DateField()
    nomer_kotl = models.ForeignKey(Nomerkotelnoy, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    choices = CHOICES)
    
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = "employee"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't set `choices` parameter on `models.ForeignKey` field.

The functionality you want is provided by [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) out of the box. Django model `ForeignKey` field gets mapped to forms [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) and that creates a dropdown populated with values from `Nomerkotelnoy`.

Change a form definition you use in your application to fix this.